# Output text as Label in GUI rather than printing Python 2

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, display

I want to create a gui window that could look like this, which lists a live feedback for the top teams and also giving them a numbering. I figured it out on creating listbox (but I would rather have label or framebox within frame like the pic).

Also, I tried to print the numbering and it works well for print function but I have no idea on how to implement this with actual fetched data to show up as GUI.

[image]

```
from urllib import urlopen
from re import findall
from Tkinter import *
from Tkinter import Tk, Label, Button

url = 'http://www.bbc.com/sport/football/premier-league/table'
EPL_contents = urlopen(url).read()
EPL_Ranking = findall("'>(\w* ?\w*)</a>", EPL_contents)
EPL_10= EPL_Ranking[:10]


root = Tk()



for index, value in enumerate(EPL_10, start=1):
        print index, value


root.mainloop()
```

Can anyone give me some hand on how I can proceed? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Label` widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/label.html) to create label, and use [`grid`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.html) or [`pack`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.html) to show the label widget.

```
for index, value in enumerate(EPL_10, start=1):
    Label(root, text=str(index)).grid(row=index, column=0, sticky='W')
    Label(root, text=value).grid(row=index, column=1, sticky='W')
```